# How to view files as a normal array

Tags: php, arrays

My main issue is that I have two different file upload links and both are for different purposes.For ex: a) Is a license b)Is a photo so I need to upload both in different locations.So what I wanted is to be able to address file properties as a numeric array instead of an associative array.I am also open to suggestions as to how to distinguish between the two files.

Here is the input code sample:

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload">
    </i>Upload License
</label>
<input id="file-upload" name="files[]" type="file">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload">
    </i>Upload Photo
</label>
<input id="file-upload" name="files[]" type="file">
```

Here is the upload script(NOTE-I have also tried using array_values())

```
<?php
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$tmpname    = array_values($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
$filename   = array_values($_FILES['files']['name']);
$filesize   = array_values($_FILES['files']['size']);
$filetype   = array_values($_FILES['files']['type']);
$date12     = date('Y-m-d');
//for photo
$file_name2 = $filename[0];
$ext2       = pathinfo($file_name2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_name22= $name.".".$ext2;
$file_size2 = $filesize[0];
$file_tmp2  = $tmpname[0];
$file_type2 = $filetype[0];
$extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","pdf","zip","rar");
$type        = "photo";
$desired_dir = "user_data";

if(in_array($ext2,$extensions ) === false)
{
    $errors2 = "Extension not allowed!";
}
else
{
    //Added file size limit
    if($file_size2 > 2097152)
    {
        $errors2 = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    if(empty($errors2) == true)
    {
        // Inserting info into database for easy retrieval
        $query1 = $this->pdo->prepare("
            INSERT into upload_data (NAME,EMAIL,FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE,date1,file_ext,type)
            VALUES('$name','$email','$file_name22','$file_size2','$file_type2','$date12','$ext2','$type')
        ");
        $query1->execute();

        if(is_dir($desired_dir) == false)
        {
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name22) == false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$type.$file_name22);
        }
        else
        {
            //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir = "user_data/".$file_name22.time();
            rename($file_tmp2,$new_dir) ;
        }
        echo "
        <script>
        Materialize.toast('Successfully Uploaded!', 8000)
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "
        <script>
        Materialize.toast($errors, 8000)
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: first of all, never use an id twice. And to adress your actual question: what have you tried, what do you get, and why does it not work?

Comment: have you tried naming them differently in html and then get the files with $_FILES['license'] and $_FILES['photo']?

Comment: Yes I have tried naming them differently as well but that does'nt seem to work.All I know is that they are not uploaded.I have an upload script as well but that is not the culprit here.I will add that too as an edit here

Comment: does your form have enctype="multipart/formdata" ?

Comment: why don't make different script for the different upload or make the ajax upload request .

Comment: Actually no so what should I do after adding that ?As in should I make 2 different fields with different names or the other method? @Cashbee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upload files in a form, your form needs enctype="multipart/form-data".
name the different inputs differently, for example license and photo. Then you can access the files in php with $_FILES['license'] and $_FILES['photo'].

Comment: Just tried the same thing again by removing some errors which were probably there in the code,now it works.Thanks for the help anyway!Your answer is anyway current.